# Data-* attr not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I cannot seem to get this data- attribute to work.  It keeps saying undefined.

JavaScript:

```
$(".navlink").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('link'));
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navlink" data-link="portfolio">
     <span class="bottom">Portfolio</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser is this in?

Comment: I'd make sure you are using the latest version. Although I too have never really gotten this to work in Chrome or IE. heh.

Comment: Oh simple PEBKAC error was using an old version of jquery I can delete this question sorry for wasting everyones time

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you have got a javascript error. it should be:

```
$(".navlink").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('link'););
})
```

always keep firebug open ;)

Comment: How could this be the answer?

Comment: After looking at it again... No idea how this supposed to work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".navlink").click(function() {
  alert( $(this).attr('data-link') );
});
```

Comment: Missing a closing parenthesis :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing `;` before closing the alert `)`. Try:

```
$(".navlink").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('link'));
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rh6ke/1/).